# Why does the jQuery slideDown function hide the scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, css

How can I hide the scrollbar of using css/jQuery? I notice that the slideDown() function makes the scrollbar to be hidden but I don't understand why (the precise reason/behaviour).

Comment: The slideDown function has nothing to do with the scrollbars. Also, make sure you accept answers for questions otherwise nobody will want to answer them.

Comment: how to accept 'em ?  i tried voteup but right not the system don't allow me i need atleast 15 points .

Comment: I just gave you an upvote to help you out. When you hit 15 points.. be sure to give upvotes where you think they're due. To accept an answer, click the checkmark next to an answer.

Comment: You accept by clicking the checkmark beside the answer that helped you most :)  Also +1 from me so you can vote on them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overflow: hidden`